# How to avoid blank rows getting replaced by nan while exporting in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on few specific columns of a dataset where having few blank rows, I am trying to clean the columns by removing all the special characters present into it. but when trying to print the columns it gives nan in place of blank rows.

Same blank rows is also getting replaced with nan while exporting to excel

**Input**

```
col1     col2    col3

AB123   BC234   cd5,8
AA001           GH002
NK01.   ZX[92   
        OP75#   ZCL02
```

**When using the below script :**

```
df[['col1','col2','col3']] = df[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
print(df[['col1','col2','col3']])
```

**Getting the output as :**

```
col1     col2    col3

AB123   BC234   cd58
AA001    nan    GH002
NK01    ZX92    nan
 nan    OP75    ZCL02
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    col1     col2    col3

    AB123   BC234   cd58
    AA001           GH002
    NK01    ZX92     
            OP75    ZCL02
```

Not expecting to get the rows filled with nan. Please suggest.

Comment: `df = df.replace('nan', "")` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your `str.replace` to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['col1','col2','col3']] = df[['col1','col2','col3']].replace('\W','', regex=True).fillna('')
```

**Output:**

```
    col1   col2    col3
0  AB123  BC234    cd58
1  AA001          GH002
2   NK01   ZX92
3          OP75  ZCL02s
```